# Anime in which a girls family is killed and there was a prophecy?

Tags: holy-knight

This anime was kind of strange but I will explain as much about it as I can,

1. There was a prophecy that had to be fulfilled, which was that this **girl** must have a child with the last descendant of the vampire slayers (I think), then kill both the child and the vampire slayer and bathe in their blood.
2. The **girl** was a vampire (I think) whose family was killed.
3. The **guy** was protected by a **cat** (an actual cat, not sure if she could transform)
4. The **guy** is in school.
5. The **guy** was reluctant to do it with a girl he just met
6. The **girl** was told this prophesy by a family member who was not present.
7. The **family** of the **girl** was killed by villagers and her **parents** sent her away to save her life.
8. This was not a recent anime (last few years) but I cant put an absolute time frame on it, sorry!
9. The **male** protagonist had **black** hair and the **relative of the girl** who had to fulfill the prophecy, had **silver** hair.

I would be grateful if you could add to this list or just give me the name of the anime, maybe adding to the character descriptions, or just the year it was released!

It was not **Omamori Himari**. It has been half a month!!! Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably specify a while ago.

Comment: Please refer to http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/892/27 and add more details to your post.

Comment: Can you describe the protagonist more specifically? (hairstyle/color, eye color, any other unusual visual content)

Comment: Was it [Omamori Himari](http://myanimelist.net/anime/6324/Omamori_Himari), per chance?

Comment: I was looking for the same one. I think it should be Holy Knight. But unfortunately there are only two episodes of it. :( I'd love to see more of it! Anyway hope this helped! :)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? show how the series match up to the description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaina Lynn didn't put this down as an answer but it was called holy knight. THANK YOU SO MUCH